# Calculate percentage of a value in a span tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form containing drop downs where a user selects a value of either 'yes' or 'no' for each question. At the bottom it then calculates how many are selected as 'yes' in a span tag.

**Is there a way I can use Javascript to calculate the percentage of the value in the first span tag, for example. If a user selects yes 12 times out of the 24 questions, then output the value as 50%?**

Here are my two span tags in question...

```
  <div class="Score">
    Total Score  = <span class="cnt-yes">0</span> out of 24 <br>
  </div>

  <div class="Percentage">
    Audit Result = <span class="cnt-percent">0</span>% <br>
  </div>
```

And here is the Javascript function that works out the values for the first span tag...

```
$('select').change(function() {
// get all selects
var allSelects = $('select');

// set values count by type
var yes = 0;
var no = 0;

// for each select increase count
$.each(allSelects, function(i, s) {
    // increase count
    if($(s).val() == 'Yes') { yes++; }
    if($(s).val() == 'No') { no++; }
});

// update count values summary
$('.cnt-yes').text(yes);
$('.cnt-no').text(no);
```

});

Here are the select tags for the first two questions as an example..

```
  <div id="hiddenQuestion1">
  <strong>1. Are the Team Players Wearing Gloves for the correct procedure?</strong> <select id="questions1" name="question1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select><br><br>
  </div>

  <div id="hiddenQuestion2" style="display:none">
  <strong>2. Are Team Players using the ESD station and signing daily sheet?</strong> <select id="questions2" name="question2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select><br><br>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add your  `<select>` element.

Comment: Explain what exactly you are struggling with …? You have your counters of `yes` and `no` already, so unless there’s a third option available, the sum of both should be the overall number of options you have. You also know how to manipulate the content of a span already, so what exactly are you still missing? The math to calculate the percentage is trivial, no?

Comment: @Piyush Suggesting external code sites is frowned upon on StackOverflow. Do not do that.

Comment: I have just asked for demo, is it wrong? I didn't know about that.

Comment: Demos should be done using Stack snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the percentage by dividing the amount of yes-answers by the total number of questions and multiplying the result by 100.
As this might result in a floating point number you should round the result afterwards.

> 12 / 24 = 0.5 * 100 = 50

So after this block:

```
$.each(allSelects, function(i, s) {
    // increase count
    if($(s).val() == 'Yes') { yes++; }
    if($(s).val() == 'No') { no++; }
});
```

insert

```
var total=Math.round(yes/24*100);
$('.cnt-percent').text(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do using vanilla Javascript:

```js
const selects = [...document.querySelectorAll('select')];

for (const select of selects) {
  select.value = '';
  select.addEventListener('change', () => {
    count.textContent = `${selects.filter(x=>x.value==='yes').length} of ${selects.length} selected 'yes'`;
    percent.textContent = `${( selects.filter(x=>x.value==='yes').length / selects.length * 100).toFixed(2)} % selected `;
  })
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>

<div id="count"></div>
<div id="percent"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
        
     ch_sel();
    }); 
     
     function ch_sel(){
         
         var target_span = $('#span1');
         
         count_yes_no(target_span);
     }
     
     
     function count_yes_no(spn) {
         
               var yes = 0;
               var no = 0;
               var l = 0;
        spn.find('select').each(function(){


           if($(this).val() == 'Yes') { yes++; }
           if($(this).val() == 'No') { no++; }  
           l++;
        });
        
        // update count values summary
        $('.cnt-yes').text(yes);
        $('.cnt-no').text(no); 
        
        $('.len').text(parseInt(l)); 
        $('.cnt-percent-y').text((yes*100 / l).toFixed(2)); 
        $('.cnt-percent-n').text((no*100 / l).toFixed(2)); 
        
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="span1">
    <select onchange="ch_sel();">
        <option value="Yes">yes</option> 
        <option value="No">no</option>
    </select>
    <select onchange="ch_sel();">
        <option value="Yes">yes</option> 
        <option value="No">no</option>
    </select>
    <select onchange="ch_sel();">
        <option value="Yes">yes</option> 
        <option value="No">no</option>
    </select>
    <select onchange="ch_sel();">
        <option value="Yes">yes</option> 
        <option value="No">no</option>
    </select>
</span>

  <div class="Score">
    Total Score  = <span class="cnt-yes">0</span> out of <span class="len">24</span> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="Score">
    Total Score  = <span class="cnt-no">0</span> out of <span class="len">24</span> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="Percentage">
    Audit Result no = <span class="cnt-percent-n">0</span>% <br>
  </div>

  <div class="Percentage">
    Audit Result yes = <span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br>
  </div>
```